# reactJS logout does not prevent back button from reentering application

Tags: reactjs

I have a reactJS application where I provide a bootstrap menu to navigate the application.  In my home page, this is the code of the menu that provides the user the link to log out:

```
<div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="/preventback">Logout</a></li>
        <li className="nav-item">
            <a className="nav-link" onClick={this.accountinformation}>Basic Account Information</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When the user clicks on the Logout link, the application will route to preventback.  This is the code in preventback.js:

```
import React from 'react';

class preventback extends React.Component {    

    componentWillMount() {
        location.href="/logout";
    }
    render() {
        return (  
            <div>     
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default preventback
```

And this is the code in my logout.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import '../styles/app.css';

class logout extends React.Component {    

render() {

        return (  
            <div className="App">      
                <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                    <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">&nbsp;</a>
                </nav>
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-12 text-center">
                                    <p className="h4">You have been logged out</p>
                                    <br /><br /><br />
                                    <div className="text-center py-4 mt-3">
                                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary"
                                            onClick={() => { 
                                            location.href = ('/') 
                                            }}>
                                            Log In
                                        </button>
                                    </div>  
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default logout
```

All this code works as expected.  When I click on the logout link, I get directed to preventback and then preventback directs me to logout.

My issue is that when I click on the browser back button, the browser takes me from the logout page to my home page.  I had anticipated it taking me from the logout page to the preventback page.  Then, when the preventback page loads, it would automatically route back to the logout page.

What am I not understanding?

Thanks.

Comment: Try clearing browser history after logout using `browserHistory.replace()`

Comment: On your click... what if you put `e.preventDefault ()`in the method handler?